# How I can find data by id of folder and response folder and children

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My json data in mongoDB, example:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "ABC",
    "parentID": null
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "ABC.txt",
    "parentID": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "ABCD",
    "parentID": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "ABC 3",
    "parentID": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "name": "ABCDFE",
    "parentID": null
  }
]
```

how can i query find only Folder1 and children of Folder1 but ignore Folder2 in mongoDB like this by nodejs expressjs:

{
"_id": 1,
"name": "ABC",
"parentID": null
},
{
"_id": 2,
"name": "ABC.txt",
"parentID": 1
},
{
"_id": 3,
"name": "ABCD",
"parentID": 1
},
{
"_id": 4,
"name": "ABC 3",
"parentID": 3
}
]

This is my code:

```
exports.getProofFolderById = async (req, res, next) => {
  const file = await Proof.find({ _id: req.params.id})
  if(!file) {
    next(new Error("Folder not found!!!"))
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    file
  })
}
```

Thanks for help me ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two documents with the same `_id`, so I assume you want to find the parent by its `name`.

One option for the query is using `$lookup`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {name: "Folder1"}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "parentID",
      as: "children"
    }
  },
  {$project: {
    children: {$concatArrays: [
          "$children", [{_id: "$_id", name: "$name", parentID: "$parentID"}]
        ]
      }
  }},
  {$unwind: "$children"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$children"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CjEtudK-Iv7)